# Templated classes, how to represent as a member variable of another class without making this class templated

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class,

```
template<typename T>
class TClass
{
public:
   //functions here
};

class Holding {
  public:

 private:
  TClass<T>  m_item;  //don't want this
};

int main() {
   Holding hd;
   //do whatever
   return 0;
}
```

I want a sort of instance variable in Holding but don't want to make Holding a template class.  What are my design options?

Comment: You can just fix `T = int` and say `TClass<int> m_item`.

Comment: But you only want a single `Holding`? Now I'm confused. Either you want one, or you want many.

Comment: Unless you know the type of the instance variable you cannot do this with c++03 features afaik. In c++11 there might be something but I don't know enough about it so you might want to look that up.

Comment: @user619818, how do you intend to use `m_item` in `Holding`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to hold any type. If that is really the case, then you could use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html):

```
class Holding {
  public:

 private:
  TClass<boost::any>  m_item;  //you want this?
};
```

If you don't use Boost, then you could implement `any` yourself or search for its implementation on this site or use google.

Comment: This is a good solution, are there any solutions not including boost though? I'm pretty interested in this idea.

Comment: @ConnorHollis: It is not difficult to implement `any` yourself. It is pretty easy!

Comment: I realize I'm really not sure what he means by his comment //don't want this

Comment: @emartel I think he meant he doesn't want to use templating for that class so he wouldn't have a T typename for that instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Derive `TClass` from a non-template base class `B` and have `Holding` hold a pointer (perhaps `std::unique_ptr`) to `B`.

Comment: Wouldn't you still have to know the type to cast it to later in this instance?

Comment: @ConnorHollis That would be necessary if you cannot create a type-agnostic abstract interface for the operations and put it in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your question properly. Basically, you have a template class TClass which needs to be configured through a template parameter. You then have Holding which owns a TClass but you don't want to make Holding a template for whatever reason.

This means that Holding needs to statically define what's the template parameter

```
TClass<SomeClass> m_item;
```

Now, you say in code you don't want this... I'm not sure if you don't want to provide a template parameter or provide T. If it's T, the code above would fix your issue. Otherwise, you'll need to use a typedef to remove the template argument and have a "template-less" type, such as:

```
typedef TClass<int> intTClass; // replace int by whatever param you want
```

which can then be used as

```
class Holding {
  public:

 private:
  intTClass m_item;  //don't want this
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use type-erasure if the possible holdings are similar enough.

```
#include <memory>

class HeldType {
public:
  virtual void myfunc() = 0;
  virtual ~HeldType() {}
};

template<typename T>
class HeldTypeModel : public HeldType {
public:
  HeldTypeModel(const T& t) : data_(t) {}
  void myfunc() { data_.myfunc(); }
private:
  T data_;
};

class TClass {
public:
  TClass() : x_(nullptr) {}

  template<typename T> 
  void set_t(const T& t) {
    x_.reset(new HeldTypeModel<T>(t));
  }

  std::unique_ptr<HeldType> x_;
};

class model {
public:
  void myfunc() {}
};

int main()
{
  TClass x;
  x.set_t(model{});
  return 0;
}
```

You need to figure out what are the commonalities between all the possible T. You probably also want to add some functions to get the `typeid` and to cast out the actual type etc. Have a look at `boost::any`.

If you are more on the experimental side of things, you can have a look at [Boost.Type Erasure](http://steven_watanabe.users.sourceforge.net/type_erasure/libs/type_erasure/doc/html/index.html), which takes away some of boiler-plate, but is not yet part of an official release.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks, I forgot to inherit. Updated with a working example.

Comment: Now all that's missing is a virtual `std::type_info` member function in the abstract base to allow sensible consumption of the derived class -- and voilà you've rewritten `boost::any` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, one benefit of this approach (and `Boost.TypeErasure`) is that you don't need to cast anymore. `boost::any` is just the least specialized version of all those functions. Have a look at Sean Parent's talk at Boostcon 2012 which makes extensive use of the idea in later parts.

Comment: Do you have a link? I only found [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpMYeUFXv8), which is apparently 100 minutes of terrible audio and a guy with a really, really boring voice. (Sorry, nothing personal, but just unwatchable.) Maybe there's a written version? [Edit:] Is Boost.TypeErasure in Boost?

Comment: @KerrekSB TypeErasure is accepted, but not merged into a release. The slides for the talk by Sean Parent are here: https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/fri/value_semantics/value_semantics.pdf?raw=true

Comment: Thanks, the slides are much better. I found the inofficial TypeErasure documentation. It's alright. It's basically a systematic set of templated mixins to provide popular features. Type erasure is generally alright if you can really manage to put *everything* you ever need of an object into a fixed virtual interface...